# Check if a document's value is in an array MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have ~ 200,000 documents in a collection which look like this:

```json
{
 "_id": "tdhABqSZPEZ2fFcEzOVCb-q8d",
 "user": "testuser",
 "content": "Test Content"
}
```

And I have an array with ~50,000 entries:

```js
let arr = ["tree", "apple", "test", "orange", ...otherEntries] // ~ 50,000 entries
```

I want to get all documents where any element of the array is in the `content` value, non case-sensitive, so that the example document above would be returned because in the array is `test` and in the content of the document is `Test`.

This would work using `$where` and then using a JavaScript expression but this is not very fast.
Is there a really fast way (< 1-2 seconds) of doing a query like this or do you have any idea on how to restructure the documents that I can perform a fast query like this?

Comment: why don't you use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/ its creating the index. So highly recommended than normal `find()`

Comment: Because I want to input an array to check if any array element is in the text and I couldn't find anything like that in Text Search

Comment: Yeah, it is, but I don't know how I would do that. Can you answer this question with this solution so I can see if it works for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you list(arr) was small => you could use make one index and use `$in` and filter  (but its not small)
- if you wanted case sensitive => you could make the list to a collection and $lookup with indexes (but you want case insensitive)

In you case that you have big list, and you want case insesitive

- join the list into a big string(lets name it `MyListString` its a variable in your driver), separated with spaces
  for example ["hat" "tree"] to become  "hat tree"
- create a text index on content its very easy to do for example in Java i did `mycoll.createIndex(Indexes.text("content"));` see your driver documentation on how to create text indexes.
- Do a find or an aggregation with match (MyListString is the above big string variable) (this does by default a case insensitive match)

  `{ "$match"  { "$text"  { "$search"  MyListString} } }`

**Time was < 1 sec** in my benchmark, test it, i think you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! That's what I've tried a few hours ago but unfortunately my problem now are two things: 1. In this large array of strings are strings with spaces. So ["abc", "def ghi", "jkl"] would become "abc def ghi jkl". So I would need to map the whole array so every string would become e. g. "\"def ghi\"" - I don't know how to do this in a fast way for such a big array. 2. I have 10 of these large arrays and I want to make only one query. Is that possible? Tried it with `$facet` but when using `$match` and `$text` in `$facet`, it throws an error since this is impossible I guess

Comment: But in fact this is the solution to my described problem

Comment: Making that big string in the driver(for example in Javascript) is very fast.Now if you have more arrays you can make 1 array with the contents of all arrays and 1 string again, it will be very fast also.I am not sure i understanded the problem. If you are stuck or query is slow maybe ask new question.